# Как удалить первый элемент коллекции, используя iterator

Tags: java

Если попытаться вызвать iterator.remove() до вызова next(), то мы получим исключение `IllegalStateException`.
Как можно удалить первый элемент коллекции, используя iterator?

```
Iterator iterator = a.entrySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    iterator.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод remove() в классе java.util.Iterator удаляет элемент, который был возвращен последним вызовом метода next(). Если вам надо удалить первый элемент именно с помощью итератора, то:

```
Iterator iterator = a.entrySet().iterator();
if(iterator.hasNext) {
    iterator.next(); // Вернет "первый" элемент
    iterator.remove(); // Удалит "первый" элемент
}
```

**Но обратите внимание!** В вашем примере вы получаете итератор коллекции реализующую интерфейс `Set` (вы получаете эту реализацию через метод `entrySet()`). Поэтому вы удаляете *первый элемент возвращаемый итератором*. Заметьте, не просто *первый элемент*, а именно *первый элемент возвращаемый итератором*, т.к. все классы реализующие интерфейс Set не дают никаких гарантий касательно порядка хранения элементов, кроме LinkedHashSet и LinkedHashMap. Если вы не используете один из этих двух последних классов, то в вашем случае вообще нельзя говорить о *первом элементе* коллекции.

И последнее - заглянув в документацию, вы могли бы сами легко ответить на собственный вопрос.